# NS_ERROR_FAILURE when synchronously getting script

Tags: jquery, firefox, get

I'm getting this error

```
"[Exception... "Failure" nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)" location: "JS frame :: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js :: .send :: line 6" data: no]"
```

When executing this request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/dg.js',
    datatype: 'script',
    async: false,
    cache: true,
    //ifModified: true,
    type: 'GET',
    data: null,
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { console.log(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown); }
})
```

Can someone reproduce it? Firefox 26 in Fedora 20

Comment: I can confirm. Slightly different jquery version: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js :: .send :: line 6`. FireFox 26 on Mint 14. Have this `.send` problem with some of my own code, which is how I found this question.

Comment: @Bryan So please confirm it [at the bug tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14726). The title there is wrong. I wrote __a__ synchronously in instead of synchronously